# Handling multiple POST requests at the same time and writing to database

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, derby

I started working with REST services recently. I have several tools joined into the framework of integrated tools. Tools communicate over the common component (CC) which handles their requests (using REST services) and is actually an interface between all the tools. For every POST request a new resource is created and stored into memory. Every time the CC goes off all the data is lost. For that case, I created an Apache Derby database to store all the resources. With every resource creation, entry is created in the database. Every time CC turns on it fetches all the data from the database and the data is regurally synced. The problem is that multiple tools can POST at almost the same time. How does REST handle these requests? I hoped that it manages the requests in a queue-like way, but from what I see it does it at the same time in a thread-like way. My database goes down instantly. Am I on the right track or something else could be wrong?[image: Tool Integration Framework]

Comment: It would be inefficient to queue requests. There's at least a handful of threads that can process them at the same time. I'd be more worried about why your database goes down. Even Derby can handle concurrent inserts.

Comment: Is there any performance tracking plugin for Eclipse so I can track the load?

Comment: You can use `visualvm` for some initial detective work.

Comment: What do you mean by "My database goes down instantly"? Is there an error message in your derby.log file?